# how to decode base64 audio data to wav format

Tags: javascript, html, recorder.js

I am recording audio in browser and wanted to save that recording on server using ajax call.

I have used recorderjs library for recording in html5 browser and its working as well.

So what I want to do is just to decode that blob/base64 data so that I can send that data to server to save.
Here is my code.

I have converted blob data to base64

```
    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function() {

                        var dataUrl = reader.result;
                        var base64 = dataUrl.split(',')[1];
/*base64 this needs to be decoded*/

                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                });
```

Comment: "base64" is not an audio format. Just do `base64_decode` on the server and save it as a file of the appropriate extension...

Comment: Actually, I don't have server side access. I can only send data and file name via ajax.

Comment: Well that's silly. In that case, you want `window.atob(base64)` to decode on the client-side. I'd like to slap the idiot who thought `atob` was a good name for "decode base64 data"...

Comment: I have already tried using window.atob(base64) but not working for me.

Comment: I don't get it, you have Base64, but you need to convert it to something to send it to the server so it can be saved, but you don't have access to the server? What does the server expect to get ?

Comment: I just wanted to form '.wav' audio data from base64 string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using base64 string I have used "dataUrl" from my code and storing this "dataUrl" data to server using Ajax.

So whenever I want to play my recorded audio i just simply get the data using ajax and response data will be added in audio source like the below code.

```
var audio_obj = new Audio();
audio_obj = data; //ajax response data
audio_obj.play();
```

Comment: Do you know how can i add the Base64 encoded data to audio.